# Is there/Can we get an easy way to view full size images?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images

I see a lot of questions where the poster has included a screenshot, but because SO scales the full-screen image down to its standard question-width, the image gets so (I forget the technical term) blurry as to be unreadable, and therefore useless.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643118/merge-cells-option-is-not-available-for-columns), for instance.

The easiest way I know to see the full-size image is to right-click it, go to properties, grab the image URL, and paste it into a browser address bar.

Any chance we could reduce this to a one- or two-click operation?  Maybe automatically make the image a link to its source?

Comment: Easier: Right Click | View Image in new Tab (chrome)