# Opening image links redirects from post

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, images

**Update**:
This got closed as a dupe, but I still wanted a popup for images.
So I made this `tampermonkey` script:
https://gist.github.com/alextartan/fc4961a7ec852ec88d57
*(not optimezed yet, but it does get the job done)*

---

**Straight to the point:**

When clicking on an image, the user is redirected to the image (in the same window).
That is counter productive, imho.

Can we open it inside a popup (lightbox-ish) or at least in a new tab (without holding `Ctrl`)?

**A bit of context:**

Yes, on SO, images are rarely useful (lots of code screenshots).
But in some cases, the user does add relevant details to the issue by posting a screenshot/image. If this weren't the case, we'd probably remove image support altogether.

So what I'm suggesting is that, if a contributor *does* want to help out and clicks the image, don't make the process more laborious (sometimes the website loads slow, the image itself may load slow, summing up some wait-time with this back-and-forth).
It's great that we have a nice community here and help each other, let's make it simpler!

---

I did some searching but all I found was:

[On click open image link to the next tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309971/on-click-open-image-link-to-the-next-tab?rq=1) (2015)

[Is there/Can we get an easy way to view full size images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296048/is-there-can-we-get-an-easy-way-to-view-full-size-images) (2015)
which is a duplicate of

[Show attached images in bigger resolution when we click on it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267606/show-attached-images-in-bigger-resolution-when-we-click-on-it) (2014)

*Note: the last link does have a comment supporting popup display of images.*

Also, it is not a duplicate of any of these. This post suggests opening the images in a popup (and only as a last resort a new tab)

**Let the vote onslaught begin ;)**

---

And it seems i wasn't wrong :)

I *am* aware of markdown limitations and even browser/user settings.
But I'm just sayin', it's 2016 and we still view images like in the ol' days.

Yeah, one could even do `Copy image location` +

```
wget --output-document logo.png \
  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d2f2059bf003de1adcf05b16aeecd5f4?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG \
  && sleep 1 && gpicview logo.png
```

But... why complicate things?

I get that users here *hate* images, but that's another issue. It's caused my the massive misuse of image uploads. I myself have seen/flagged/commented posts with images of code.
I'm talking here about 'good' images. And yes, there are a bunch of them.

Stackechange is full of javascript. This page alone has 12 `<script>` blocks.

There **is already** a similar popup. The one shown when hovering the user profiles logo (for users with extended details - I have one, [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) too..).

So why neglect UX?

Comment: *"But I'm just sayin', it's 2016 and we still view images like in the ol' days."*, yes, that's because that's **the right way to view images**. It is up to you and your browser to decide how to open a link, not for each individual site to impose specific one-off functionality that you may or may not want. Want a new tab? Hold control and click the link. "Neglecting UX" is what you are *proposing*, not the current state of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't force how links behave.

Depending on user settings, browser defaults, and the alignment of the stars, links will open in the same page, a new tab, a new window, or not at all.

Even if a `target` is specified, it's still dependent on user settings whether or not the target setting is respected.

If a user wants to open a image in a new tab, that user should do that themselves.
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Click</kbd> / <kbd>Scrollwheel Click</kbd>)

Opening links in popups is just asking for bug reports, as a lot of users have configured their browsers to block popups.

---

Markdown offers no support for any kind of "Target":
`[![wolf][1]][1]`

[image: wolf]

And a anchor tag (`<a>`) doesn't work when you add a `target`, probably for security reasons:
`<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOf0S.png" target="_blank">![wolf][1]</a>`

[image: wolf]

Notice that the `<a>` works without `target`:
`<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOf0S.png">![wolf][1]</a>`

[image: wolf]

---

You ask:

*"So why neglect UX?"*

I'd argue that trying to **alter default browser behavior** results in **bad UX**. Clicking an image will then work different on SO than it does on all other sites a user visits. Unexpected behavior like that usually isn't appreciated.

Let's keep it simple.

If a user wants to open a image in a new tab, he'll use one of the many ways he's been using forever, to do so.

Comment: I fully agree with the "new tab" aspect. That's why I put it second. My first option would be a popup.

Comment: @AlexTartan: See my latest edit.

Comment: I'm rather curious why I got downvoted. This is just a simple fact of web development...

Comment: Someone disagrees with you, but they're wrong.

Comment: Alright, I give up :)) You *do* make a valid point.